# Finding the value of $a^x$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

We have the series expansion $e^x = 1 + \frac{x}{1!}+ \frac{x^2}{2!}+ \frac{x^3}{3!}+ \frac{x^4}{4!}...\infty$. Is it possible to write $a^x$ in the similar form, where `a` is an integer and `x` could be any real value?

Comment: $a^x = e^{x.\ln(a)} = 1 + x.\ln(a)/1! + (x.\ln(a))^2/2! + \cdots\;$ but maybe this is not what you mean.

Comment: @HandeBruijn It's ok. I ll give a try..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the standard definition is $a^x=e^{x\ln a}$, and you have already defined $e^y$ for any $y$.
The definition of $\ln a$ is $\ln a = \int_1^a \frac{1}{x} dx$.
I know it looks weird, but it turns out that this definition agrees with $a^n=a*a*...*a$ for any integer $n$, and also $a^{x+y}=a^xa^y$.
As a sanity check, look at $2^{0.001}$ on your calculator, and compare it with $\ln 2$.

Comment: that's a nice method... I ll try it.